# Trigger with specific value?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I've read some questions/answers here on Stack but couldn't find anything like what I need.
Let's say I have the following table:

```
col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
----  ----  ----  ----  ----
8     1     a     b     c
8     2     a     b     c
8     3     a     b     c
9     1     a     b     c
9     2     a     b     c
```

And my software does:

```
INSERT INTO testtable ([col0],[col1],[col2],[col3],[col4]) 
  VALUES ('8','4','a','b','c')
```

How can I create a trigger like this pseudo-code:

```
On insert when col1 = '4'
  delete existing rows where col0 is the same (8 in this case)
   ** except for the new row I've just added **
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more appropriate to perform this in an instead of trigger. If the goal is what I assume: when a new row is inserted with col0 = 8, you want to delete all other rows with that same key, yes?

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.testtable_instead_insert
ON dbo.testtable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DELETE t 
    FROM dbo.testtable AS t
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON t.col0 = i.col0
    WHERE i.col1 = '4';

  INSERT dbo.testtable(col0,col1,col2,col3,col4)
    SELECT col0,col1,col2,col3,col4
      FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

The question is what rule do you want to follow if an insert attempts to add multiple rows with the same col0 value? Imagine the insert statement is:

```
INSERT dbo.testtable ([col0],[col1],[col2],[col3],[col4]) 
SELECT '8','4','a','b','c'
UNION ALL 
SELECT '8','3','c','d','e';
```

Comment: I haven't explained correctly. (Sorry my english). Yes, 8 is the key value, but the "mark" is col1, let's say: I can insert dozens of lines with same key, but, when one of those lines is "4" at col1 it would delete all the others with key 8.

Comment: Ok, updated to what I think you want now. Still not sure what you want to do with duplicates, though.

Comment: Aaron, it's working. I've checked the software, it's a simple INSERT, nothing special, I just don't have the source to fix what I need :(. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (on a test server):

```
DELETE FROM TESTTABLE T1
    JOIN INSERTED T2
        ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1
        AND T1.COL0 = T2.COL0
```

Comment: But '8' is an example value, it's inserted with the INSERT statement, not a fixed value.

Comment: Like this (see edit)? You're trying to delete previous duplicates of Col1 and Col0? Do you have and ID field on the testtable? I'm worried that my solution will delete the one inserted, too, but if there's an ID field you can say "WHERE T1.ID <> T2.ID".

Comment: Yes, this deletes all values for the same col0, including the one(s) you just inserted. Doing this in an after trigger is problematic because it might be impossible to tell, after the fact, which rows came from the insert that fired the trigger, and which ones already existed and happened to have the same values in the key columns.

Comment: Right, another reason you should generally have an IDENTITY field where possible.

Comment: Oh, I disagree with that. `IDENTITY` columns are useful, sure, but this isn't a valid reason to slap one on a table. There may be natural key information we don't know about, for example, and as my solution proposed, an instead of trigger can tell the inserted rows from the pre-existing rows.